# update portion of Kendo code without updating everything

Tags: kendo-ui

We're in a situation where we can't upgrade Kendo due to the fact that a number of changes were made to the CSS files and we don't have the time right now for additional QA (However we are planning to go the proper upgrade route in the next version of our product).

in versions prior to 2013 Q3 SP1 the kendo.toString function didn't format very small decimal numbers correctly, which we know has been fixed since then:

http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui-web/release-history/q3-2013-sp1-web

Is it possible to somehow grab the .toString function from the latest version and plug it into the old 2013 version? And how? I've scanned through the Kendo min file, but it looks dangerous. I was actually hoping there was a way to patch it by adding an additional file that would override the function, but it doesn't look as if Kendo works that way.

Answer (score 0):

That part of Kendo is open source, so you can get the new implementation from here:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.core.js#L1048-L1058

Then you can just replace `kendo.toString` with your own implementation, something like:

```
var fixedToString = function () { ...};
kendo.toString = fixedToString;
```

However internally some parts of Kendo might hold the old implementation in a closure, so it might not work everywhere. It's worth a try though...